# Iterative calculation to find desired number

Tags: excel, circular-reference

I am trying to use a circular reference with iterative calculations to find a specific number however my file will not display the number. I turn iterative calculations but it fluctuates wildly even though there is a definitive answer. I have included an image of my example.

[image]

Comment: There is a reason the circular reference are not allowed in Google Sheets.  You will want to use the solver and not circular references, or vba.  Circular references are not something one wants to rely on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, circular references are a result of an incorrect structure in formulas. Enabling iterative calculations is not a solution to this problem. They are only intended in situations where repeatedly performing a calculation will lead to stable result.

(An example of useful iterative calculations is field analysis. You can define values around the edge of a field of any shape. In the interior, the value of every point is the average of all the points around it. After several thousand iterations, everything will stabilise to an evenly distributed field.)

In your situation, iterative calculations does not lead to a stable result. When Ending Cash is -300, the Cash Deposit is set to 300. But then the Ending Cash is 0, so the Cash Deposit is set to 0. But then the End Cash is -300, so the Cash Deposit is set to 300, ad finitum.

The calculation of how much Cash Deposit is required to ensure the End Cash is greater than or equal to 0 can't be based on the End Cash or the Total Deposit, as it will keep contradicting itself as to whether or not a Cash Deposit is required.

Instead, the calculation of how much Cash Deposit is required must look at all other deposits excluding itself and compare that to the total withdrawls. (By not referring to the Total Deposits or End Cash, there is no circular reference). It can be set up as:

`=IF(B2+B5<B14,B14-(B2+B5),0)`

It adds together all other Deposits *excluding* itself and compares that to the Total Withdrawals to determine whether any additional deposit is required. If an additional deposit is required, it then subtracts all other Deposits from the Total Withdrawals to find out how much it needs to be.

A more elegant way of writing such a formula is:

`=MAX(B14-B5-B2,0)`

This simply subtracts all deposits from the total withdrawal, and returns the difference if it is needed when it is positive (more withdrawals), or returns 0 if it is not needed when the difference is negative (more deposits).

Comment: Thank you, you make a ton of sense. I am working on a financial model and was overthinking it.  Your proposed solution works and is simple to use.  Appreciate your insight on iterative calculations.